# Tooltipster .tooltipster('open') throwing error.

Tags: javascript, tooltipster

I am having problem with `Tooltipster`. Can't figure out why 'open' is not working, while according to documentation it should?

I have setup it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lapkritinis/9gj8c57w/)

HTML

```
<button id="broken" title="Broken Tooltip">Broken</button>
```

JS:

```
  $('#broken').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#broken').tooltipster('open');
  });
```

But it throws error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unknown method .tooltipster("open")
<...?
```

Replacing `'open'` with `'destroy'` for example works fine.

Anyone can figure out what I am doing wrong? Or broken tooltipster itself?

Comment: You want to show the tooltip on click?

Comment: @Justcode Yes. I want to show "Copied!" when user clicks button to copy to clipboard.

Comment: I will open issue on github. Seems like legit bug case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [trigger:'click'](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#options) in tooltipster

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').tooltipster({

  });

  $('#broken').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'click'
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.3.0/css/tooltipster.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.3.0/js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>
<button id="search" title="Tooltip Working">Search</button>

<button id="broken" title="Broken Tooltip">Broken</button>
```

Comment: Working workaround. Would serve my intended purpose if I add timeout to hide message. However still interested why 'open' doesn't work.

Comment: @lapkritinis I think you are correct, I saw you opened new ticket in repo, here is the link for feature ones. https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/issues/751

Comment: @lapkritinis I think it is deprecated in latest version, here is the working version http://jsfiddle.net/m9she00L/2/

Comment: Actually library version on cdnjs.com is old (3.3.0 which is not working 'open' and which I am using vs 4.2.6 on github). There is some issue ongoing to pull latest version to cdnjs https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/pull/12239

Answer (score 1):

try to `trigger: 'click'` example http://jsfiddle.net/9gj8c57w/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').tooltipster({

  });

  $('#broken').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'click'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.3.0/js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.3.0/css/tooltipster.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<button id="search" title="Tooltip Working">Search</button>

<button id="broken" title="Broken Tooltip">Broken</button>
```